# Подсчет среднего арифметического числа с квотами для каждой группы чисел c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Решил изобразить визуально, чтобы было больше понятно.

Задача:

Есть 4 значиния (double) и среди них надо найти среднее арифметическое. Но у каждого значения есть своя квота (проценты):
 - Серый цвет сразу без обработки можно считать. 
 - Каждое цветное значение проверяется на условия

Задача 1:

```
  if(blue1>100){//код}
  if(blue2>100){//код}      
  if(blue3>100){//код}
```

если все три значения возвращают true, то

```
   (blue1+blue2+blue3)/3
```

но если один if вернет false, надо сделать

```
   (blue1+blue3)/2
```

Задача 2

Если например все три групы значений вернут true, то проблем с подсчетом нет. Но если например все зеленые, то тогда квота других должна соответствовать 45%  и 45%

Вопрос 1. Как написать такой метод, чтобы делитель всегда соотвествовал количеству true значений и если все вернут false, то чтобы не было деления на ноль?

Вопрос 2. Как разделить эти квоты, чтобы даже если true вернет только 1 цветное значение, оно подсчитывалось как 90%

Может уже готовый метод есть, который будет принимать нужное количество значений? Я пытался сделать через if а количетсво делителей получал тем, что добавлял true в коллекцию и потом ".Count" но в таком количестве if можно просто допустить ошибку и вообще сложно разобратся.

Comment: Ваши значения как заданы: имеются четыре коллекции (красная, зеленая, синяя, серая) или одна коллекция, в которой объекты со свойством `цвет` (условно)?

Comment: @alexander-petrov цвет это одна коллекция, в которой будет 0, 1, 2 или 3 поля (максимум 3), среди которых надо посчитать средн.арифметическое

Comment: Как-то всё описано непонятно. Давайте так — без всяких цветов и прочего, напишите что вы имеете на входе (коллекция чего-то или структура какая-то), опишите алгоритм для обработки этого и добавьте пару примеров входных и выходных данных.

Comment: Хорошо. Значит все цвета это поля double . Double получаем при парсинге сайта, Например
 три зелёных круга это 1.5, 2.0, 0.8. Надо подсчитать среднее арифметическое которое будет  1.43. Но парсер может вернуть два значения, например 3.3 и 1.2, тогда среднее значение будет 2.25. а может ничего не вернуть. Тогда надо не учитывать коллекцию "три цветных круга" при дальнейшем вычислении

Comment: Так в чем у вас проблема при реализации вашего алгоритма?

Comment: [`Average`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=netframework-4.7.2) не подходит что ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не понял, но предложу такое решение:

```
var avg = colors.Where(c => c > 100).DefaultIfEmpty().Average();
```

Берем только те цвета из коллекции цветов, которые имеют значение больше 100 и потом находим среднее арифметическое. Если после `Where` не останется ни одного элемента — берем значение по умолчанию с помощью `DefaultIfEmpty`.